# python - how to reduce repetitive try/catch blocks?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and am writing a CLI wrapper for an internal tool using a python wrapper to a C++ API, and find myself constantly defining functions with identical try/catch blocks inside of them, with the only difference being the single call to the API.

For example...

```
px5 = PX5()

try:
  px5.connect()
except PX5Exception:
  for te in px5.errors:
    print(te)

def some_action(some_val):
  try:
    px5.run_method(some_val)
  except PX5Exception:
    for te in px5.errors:
      print(te)
    exit()

def some_other_action(some_val):
  try:
    return px5.run_some_other_method(some_val)
  except PX5Exception:
    for te in px5.errors:
      print(te) 
    exit()
```

Am I just way overdoing it with the try/catch blocks? Each individual command I need to run can easily have exceptions that I want to catch and display in a friendly manner vs. displaying the entire exception (basically, as the tool itself would display them if you weren't going through the API and using the CLI directly).

Comment: What happens to the caller of `some_action`? As it stands here, they get returned `None` whether or not some exceptions were printed, which means they'll go on to do whatever they would do next, succeed or fail. If your intent is to convert raised exceptions into logic for displaying errors in a nice friendly fashion, that should usually happen towards the very outer layers of the program, which means you don't wrap these repetitive try blocks around every action, since you want any exceptions to halt processing and propagate outwards to the outer layers.

Comment: apologies, I used dummy examples that weren't the best. updated... each try/catch block may return a value or just run the command if I didn't care about the return value, and if an exception is thrown, I would exit after displaying the errors.

Comment: In that case especially then, just put your try/except block in one place way up in the call graph (maybe in your entry point function, even). Whenever `some_action` is called, if it encounters an exception you *don't* handle it there (so no need for try/except boilerplate), the exception will unwind the stack all the way to the single outer handler, which will print the errors and then exit.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to make a wrapper method:

```
def print_errors(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    except PX5Exception:
        for te in px5.errors:
            print(te)
```

Then instead of a try/except block each time, you'd just wrap:

```
print_errors(px5.run_some_other_method, some_val)
```

Comment: Unbelievable... Is that rainbow horse?